# Maven dependencies issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm seein a bit of a weird problem with maven sometimes. I use maven together with eclipse, using eclipse to code and maven to build and deploy.

However, sometimes,

```
mvn compile
```

will fail on the command line. due to missing dependencies. If i do a Maven->update dependencies and Maven-update project configuration , it will fix it so i can do a

```
mvn compile
```

I'm a bit confused about this, I could understand it if it was the other way around (if i had issues from within eclipse) due to problem with the .classpath files or something like that.

Comment: Could you provide us with the pom.xml in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
mvn -U compile
```

On the command line. This forces an update of dependencies.